# withThrowingTaskGroup - No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

### Problem:

I have the following function which shows a warning `No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression`

### Questions:

- Why is this warning shown? (The code inside the task throws an error)
- What should I do to propagate the error to the caller of `f1`?

### Code:

```
func f1() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Int.self) { group in //No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
        group.addTask(priority: .high) {
            throw NSError()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You indeed have not called any throwing functions, or thrown anything, in the `withThrowingTaskGroup` closure. You've just added a task for the group to run. This by itself won't throw anything. [`addTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/throwingtaskgroup/3862711-addtask?changes=_4) is not marked `throws`, though its closure parameter is. It will only throw when you wait for the task's completion in one way or another.

For example:

```
try await group.waitForAll()
```

Or if you want to loop through each task of the group:

```
for try await someInt in group {
    // ...        
}
```

If you return something in the `withThrowingTaskGroup` closure, that's what `withThrowingTaskGroup` will return too. If you throw an error in the closure, `withThrowingTaskGroup` will throw that error (since it is `rethrows`), and so will `f1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, just curious wouldn't `withThrowingTaskGroup` wait for all tasks to complete even if `group.waitForAll()` is not invoked?

Comment: @user1046037 Yes it will, according to the documentation. Normally you would do wait for one or more tasks in the group and get some kind of result for `withThrowingTaskGroup` to return, and this would be a throwing operation. But you are not doing that here, hence the warning. If you are not planning on awaiting any values from the group, then `waitForAll` is just a way to silence the warning.

Comment: This was also what was required for the underlying errors to be thrown. While I did have `try await withThrowingTaskGroup`, errors in the tasks added were not being propagated until I added this line. Thank you!